# Why does the default Apache XML config file parse?

Tags: xml, apache

I noticed this default Apache configuration in Ubuntu server:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note the `<Directory />` line which specifies that the directory being configured is `/` (Compare with `<Directory /var/www/>`). However, in XML ending a tag with the `/` character specifies a a self-closing tag.

Should I therefore conclude that the default Apache configuration just looks like XML, but is not meant to be XML. It also has no doctype and supports `#` comments.

Comment: Note that "XML" appears nowhere on the ["configuring" page in documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html).

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I guess even if it looks like a duck, its not a duck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question. It's not XML. I don't know why they chose to use something that superficially resembles XML, but that's what they did.